# Bootstrap "row row-md" or "row row-cols" don't seem to work with images?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

The images don't break as they should, not at all. If I replace the image line with something like `<h1></h1>`  , then it works. Why not with images? I tried `div class="col col-lg-2 col-md-3"` too but didn't work. I'm 100% sure it's something simple and my brain is too smooth...

```
<div class="container">

        <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#gallery button">Simple collapsible</button>
        
        <div id="gallery button" class="collapse">

            <section class="gallery min-vh-100">

                <div class="row row-md-3">
                    <div class="col">
                        <img src="images/art_img000.jpg" class="gallery-item">
                    </div>  
                
                    <div class="col">
                        <img src="images/art_img000.jpg" class="gallery-item">
                    </div>  
                
                    <div class="col">
                        <img src="images/art_img000.jpg" class="gallery-item">
                    </div>  
                
                    <div class="col">
                        <img src="images/art_img000.jpg" class="gallery-item">
                    </div>                  
                </div> 
                
            </section>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to add the class `w-100` to the images?

Comment: I tried it now but nothing changes.

Comment: Where's your CSS? What's the expected output? What *didn't work*? Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue, along with a clear description of the problem and debugging details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a few mistakes:

- Using `data-toggle` and `data-target` (Bootstrap 4) instead of `data-bs-toggle` and `data-bs-target` (Bootstrap 5). I assume you want to use Bootstrap 5.
- Not following Bootstrap HTML as shown in the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/collapse/#example). If you don't follow Bootstrap HTML, the components won't work.
- Trying to use the class `row-md-3` as a Bootstrap class. This is not a Bootstrap class! See the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/).
- Not using `col-md-3` correctly.

See the snippet below.

If the window width is greater than `768px`, the images will be shown side by side. If the window width is equal to or less than `768px`, the images will be stacked. See the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/breakpoints/#available-breakpoints).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#gallery-button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="gallery-button">
    Button with data-bs-target
  </button>
  <div id="gallery-button" class="collapse">
    <section class="gallery min-vh-100">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="images/art_img000.jpg" class="gallery-item">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="images/art_img000.jpg" class="gallery-item">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="images/art_img000.jpg" class="gallery-item">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="images/art_img000.jpg" class="gallery-item">
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```